# Ansible Command module says that '|' is illegal character

Tags: shell, dpkg, ansible

I am using Ansible to deploy my project and I trying to check if an specified package is installed, but I have a problem with it task, here is the task:

```
- name: Check if python-apt is installed
  command: dpkg -l | grep python-apt
  register: python_apt_installed
  ignore_errors: True
```

And here is the problem:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts idempotent.yml

PLAY [lxc-host] *************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [10.0.3.240]

TASK: [idempotent | Check if python-apt is installed] ************************* 
failed: [10.0.3.240] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["dpkg", "-l", "|", "grep", "python-apt"], "delta": "0:00:00.015524", "end": "2014-07-10 14:41:35.207971", "rc": 2, "start": "2014-07-10 14:41:35.192447"}
stderr: dpkg-query: error: package name in specifier '|' is illegal: must start with an alphanumeric character
...ignoring

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
10.0.3.240                 : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Why is illegal this character **'|'** .

Comment: Btw, according to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/4617 `python-apt` should be automatically installed when you use `apt` module, so you shouldn't need to manually bootstrap it.

Comment: use `shell` module if you want to use `pipe`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

From the doc:

> [**command** - Executes a command on a remote node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html)
>
> The command module takes the command name followed by a list of
> space-delimited arguments. The given command will be executed on all
> selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so
> variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will
> not work (use the shell module if you need these features).
>
> [**shell** - Executes a commands in nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)
>
> The shell module takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments.
> It is almost exactly like the command module but runs the command
> through a shell (/bin/sh) on the remote node.

Therefore you have to use `shell: dpkg -l | grep python-apt`.

Comment: My mistake was to use command rather than shell. I also have to ignore the error the first time and then when the python-apt package is installed, the check task doesn't fail. Thank you.

Answer (score 43):

read about the [command module in the Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html):

> It will not be processed through the shell, so .. operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work

As it recommends, use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html):

```
- name: Check if python-apt is installed
  shell: dpkg -l | grep python-apt
  register: python_apt_installed
  ignore_errors: True
```

For what it's worth, you can check/confirm the installation in a debian environment using [the `apt` command](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html):

```
- name: ensure python-apt is installed
  apt: name=python-apt state=present
```

Comment: If I want to use the apt module, is necessary installed first. I do the confirmation only the first time and later I use apt module to install packages. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think this is a better aproach, using modules that interact directly with packages.

Comment: @rob3 wait, what confirmation? you can certainly use `apt` to install modules and verify they are installed. Both debian and ubuntu have apt already, and `python-apt` doesn't have any manual installation steps.

Comment: yes, but from documentation the first note says: **Requires python-apt**. Then the first task is install python-apt and then I can use it for install others packages.

Comment: @Rob3 it seems strange, but you can use apt to install python-apt.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. More straightforward than @Sylvain's.