# Counting number of files and removing all but the 10 newest with Ansible tasks

Tags: shell, ansible

First I used the shell module to send a command that will count the number of files in each path and register the output into a variable.

```
- name: Count files in backups
  shell:
    cmd: ls | wc -l
    chdir: '{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/fullWP'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/coreWP'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/mysql'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/archive'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/config'
  register: number_files
  tags: clear.files
```

The following task is supposed to run a command to each file path that counted more than 10 files in the directory.

```
- name: Delete the oldest backups
  shell:
    cmd: ls -t | tail -n +11 | xargs rm
    chdir: '{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/fullWP'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/coreWP'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/mysql'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/archive'
    - '/home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/config'
  when: number_files.stdout > 10 == true
  tags: clear.oldFiles
```

My error tells me that I have an undefined variable but am unsure how to fix this.

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'value'\n\
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, see the playbook below.

- Use `find` module to create a list of the files `result.files`.
- In the next task create list `files_rm` of the files to be removed. Sort the list by `mtime` (`atime` and `ctime` are also available), map the attribute `path` and select all items in the list but first `backup_keep` (10).
- For security reason, the removal of the files is disabled by default.

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    backup_dir: backups
    backup_keep: 10
    dry_run: true
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: "{{ backup_dir }}"
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        files_rm: "{{ (result.files|
                      sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true)|
                      map(attribute='path')|
                      list)[backup_keep:] }}"
    - debug:
        var: files_rm
    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files_rm }}"
      when: not dry_run|bool
```

---

**Example**

Let's create 5 files in the directory `backups`

```sh
shell> for i in {1..5}; do touch backups/backup-$i; done
```

```sh
shell> tree backups/
backups/
├── backup-1
├── backup-2
├── backup-3
├── backup-4
└── backup-5

0 directories, 5 files
```

For testing, let's set `backup_keep: 3` to keep the last 3 backup files. The playbook gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  files_rm:
  - backups/backup-2
  - backups/backup-1

TASK [file] ****
skipping: [localhost] => (item=backups/backup-2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=backups/backup-1)
```

This is what we want. Obsolete 2 backup files will be removed. Let's remove the files. The playbook gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "dry_run=False"

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  files_rm:
  - backups/backup-2
  - backups/backup-1

TASK [file] ****
changed: [localhost] => (item=backups/backup-2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=backups/backup-1)
```

```sh
shell> tree backups/
backups/
├── backup-3
├── backup-4
└── backup-5

0 directories, 3 files
```

The playbook is idempotent

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "dry_run=False"

ok: [localhost] => 
  files_rm: []
```

Comment: My debug is telling me that the variable 'file_rm' is undefined. set_fact does not seem to be working.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I still do not understand why 'set_fact' is not registering the variable. Otherwise it looks like this would work, I think I may just use the script module instead to run a shell script on the remote machine with will achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Wannabe Geek, pipes in ansible command module don't work, you need to go with shell module for using pipes. Check out the answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679591/ansible-command-module-says-that-is-illegal-character)